# MouseMotionListener is not capturing Point fast enough

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, point, mousemotionlistener

I started a school project trying to draw 9*9 and 17*17 pixels JPanels on a bigger JPanel, imitating a pen in Gimp for instance.
I tried to capture the mouse position using MouseClicked to start, MouseDragged to listen and repaint() the (big)JPanel where i want the pen to draw and MouseReleased to record.

The problem is that the MouseDragged does not listen enough to the mouse so i get random points if i move to fast.

Here is my MVC pattern, Create.java - DrawGame.java - ControleurGame.java

WHat do you think would be best ?

```
package controleur;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import vue.*;
import vue.Draw.*;
import vue.DrawGame.*;
import modele.*;




/**
*
* @author Yann
*/

public class ControleurGame extends ControleurDraw implements MouseMotionListener {

  int mode;
  Area zone;
  Create draw;

  public ControleurGame (Background bg, JButton[] jip, Utilisateur uti, int n, Area j, Create d) {

    super(bg);
    user = uti;
    butts = jip;
    mode = n;
    zone = j;
    draw = d;

    resume = new JLabel (user.toString());
    resume.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    resume.setBounds(45,600,256+128,32);
    resume.setVisible(true);

    pan.add(resume);
    pan.add(zone);
    pan.repaint();

  }

  @Override
  public void focusGained (FocusEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
      but = (JButton)e.getSource();
      but.setSelected(true);
      pan.repaint();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void focusLost (FocusEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
      but = (JButton)e.getSource();
      but.setSelected(false);
      pan.repaint();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
      if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        but = (JButton)e.getSource();
        but.doClick();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    draw.pixels.add(draw.index,new ArrayList<Point>());
    draw.pixels.get(draw.index).add(e.getPoint());
    System.out.println(e.getPoint().toString());
    zone.addP((int)e.getPoint().getX(),(int)e.getPoint().getY());
    pan.repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    draw.pixels.get(draw.index).add(e.getPoint());
    System.out.println(e.getPoint().toString());
    zone.addP((int)(e.getPoint().getX()),(int)e.getPoint().getY());
    pan.repaint();


  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    draw.index++;
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    if (draw.dragging) {

    }
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    pan.repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
      but = (JButton)e.getSource();
      but.setSelected(false);
    }

    pan.repaint();
  }

}
```

Create.java

```
package modele;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
*
* @author Matthew
*/

public class Create {

  public static boolean dragging = false;
  public int index = 0;
  public ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> pixels;

  public Create () {
    pixels = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
  }

}
```

DrawGame.java

```
package vue;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import controleur.*;
import modele.*;



/**
*
* @author Yann
*/

public class DrawGame extends Draw {

  int mode = 0;
  Area tableau;
  Create dessin;

  public DrawGame (int n, Utilisateur u) {
    super(n);

    user = u;
    library();
    dessin = new Create();
    try {tableau = new Area();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    poulet = new ControleurGame(fond,butts,user,mode,tableau,dessin);

    tableau.addMouseMotionListener(poulet);
    tableau.addMouseListener(poulet);
    fond.add(tableau);
    fond.repaint();

  }

  public class Area extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("../src/png/game/01AreaHL.png"));

    public Area () throws IOException {

      this.setLayout(null);
      this.setBounds(10,50,515,450);
      this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void addP (int n, int m) {
      try {this.add(new Pix(n,m));} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();};
    }

    public class Pix extends JPanel {

      BufferedImage bp;
      Random rand = new Random();

      public Pix (int n, int m) throws IOException {

        try {bp = ImageIO.read(new File("../src/png/game/Points16-2/1602"+rand.nextInt(8)+".png"));} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBounds(n-8,m-8,17,17);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));


      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bp, 0, 0, null);
      }
    }

  }

  public void library() {

    try {icons[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("../src/png/game/00FondGame.png"));}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

  }

  public static void main (String[] args){
    DrawGame d = new DrawGame(1, Database.getUser("n0x"));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the MouseDragged does not listen enough to the mouse so i get random points if i move to fast.

Yes, you will never get all the points when the mouse is moved fast.

The solution is to change your painting code to draw lines between two points.

So you need to iterate through your ArrayList that contains your Points. Draw an line between the first and second, then the second and third etc.

Comment: thanks a lot at least it's clear
you are sure there is no other way ?
Another listener or a thread or something ?